# Mojolicious : syntax-highlighting for inlined templates

Tags: perl, templates, syntax-highlighting, mojolicious

Would it be in principle possible to ( additionally ) create something like a **TEMPLATE** section for inlining the templates to make it easier to create a suitable syntax-highlighting for the template, since the **DATA** section has mostly its own syntax-highlighting?

Answer (score 4):

You didn't mention what text editor are you using, but for VIM there is a [Mojo templates Syntax file](https://github.com/yko/mojo.vim) that can highlight .ep and .epl Mojolicious templates in `__DATA__` sections.

Comment: I'm using KWrite as editor, but I still tried to test mojo.vim. Unfortunately I had problems with the installation of `Text:: VimColor`(I suppose `Text::VimColor` is required for mojo.vim). Since Vim is not my first-choice-editor I didn't pursue the `Text::VimColor` installationsproblems.

Answer (score 3):

I just recently read [Ovid's article on highlighting SQL HEREDOCs](http://blogs.perl.org/users/ovid/2011/06/syntax-highlight-your-sql-heredocs-in-vim.html).  I think similar approach could be used for templates.